# Can someone explain System.out.println(args[0]);

Tags: java

When I try to run this code

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(args[0]);
    }
}
```

it throws this exception

```
Exception in thread "main"
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at Test.main(Test.java:3)
```

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: You need to pass some arguments when running your program (at least one).

Comment: Are you coming from a `C` background? `Java` does *not* print the name of the file like `C` would with `argv[0]`

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `args` parameter is passed to the `main` method when the application is run.  If no arguments are passed to the application accessing the first index of the `args` array will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Try running your application from the command line as follows:

```
cd /Whatever/directory/contains/the/class
javac Test.java
java Test a b c
```

If you are using the Eclipse IDE program arguments can be set by Run > Run Configurations and then selecting your program and supplying arguments.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Run your program like

```
java Test foobar
```

`foobar` is `arg[0]`.

You should check array sizes, though.

Answer (score 1):

Run it as

```
$ java Test foo
```

which will print

```
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Run it with something like this:

```
java package.to.Test arg0 arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand, an out-of-bounds array exception means that you've tried to access an array index that isn't populated by a value.  In this case, no data was passed in to args.  You can set arguments in Eclipse or specify them when you run your program from the command line, etc.